# How to drop rows in multiple DataFrames?

Tags: pandas

I've got multiple DataFrames, each with a column named 'Year' and each containing rows from 1979 through 2014. I'd like to be able to loop over my list of DataFrames and apply the same selection criteria to each DataFrame and only keep a subset of the rows.

My example DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Year": np.arange(1979,2015)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Year": np.arange(1979,2015)})
```

My loop:

```
for df in [df1, df2]:
    df = df[(df['Year'] <= 2013)]
```

That code doesn't drop the last rows of the DataFrames, though.
    df1.tail()
has all the rows that the original DataFrames had.

This works, though:

```
foo1 = df1[(df1['Year'] <= 2013)]
foo2 = df2[(df2['Year'] <= 2013)]
```

I have too many DataFrames to loop over to want to do it on a DataFrame-by-DataFrame basis, and would really like to have it work within a loop.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign output to the `list`, because is not possible to modify original `DataFrame`s:

```
dfs = []
for df in [df1, df2]:
    dfs.append(df[(df['Year'] <= 2013)])
```

Or use `list comrehension`:

```
dfs = [df[(df['Year'] <= 2013)] for df in [df1, df2]]
```

---

If want `dictionary of DataFrames` is possible use `zip`:

```
names = ['a','b'] 
dfs = dict(zip(names, [df[(df['Year'] <= 2013)] for df in [df1, df2]]))
print (dfs['a'])
```

Comment: Thanks. But then I lose the ability to reference the original DataFrame by its name, right?

Comment: Yes, but then is possible create `dictinary of dataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a different object to a name, the previous object the name referred to does not change.

For example, let

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a
```

Now if I go ahead and point `b` to another object, `a` will stay the same:

```
b = [4, 5]
a
Out: [1, 2]
```

But instead of pointing b to another object, I can modify the object it points to:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a
b.append(3)  
a
Out: [1, 2, 3]
```

In your for loop, these happen:

- The name `df` points to `df1` (Start of the loop)
- The name `df` points to another object (which is `df1[(df1['Year'] <= 2013)]`)
- The name `df` points to `df2` (second iteration)
- The name `df` points to another object (which is `df2[(df2['Year'] <= 2013)]`)

So you are not actually changing `df1` or `df2`, you are just giving another target to `df`. If you print `df` at the end of the loop you'll see that it will print `df2[(df2['Year'] <= 2013)]`.

What you can do is to modify/mutate the object:

```
for df in [df1, df2]:
    df.drop((df[(df['Year'] > 2013)]).index, inplace=True)
    # df = df.drop((df[(df['Year'] > 2013)]).index) wouldn't work
```

Here, we are not pointing `df` to another object; instead, we are changing the object at the target. If you print out `df1` or `df2` you'll see that they have changed.

So your options are either to change the DataFrames in place (if the methods allow you to do so), or store the DataFrames in a collection and change the objects in the collection like jezrael did.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!

It seems like the `.index` is key. (Though I don't fully understand why...)

Comment: @kxp `.index` is required for this specific method (`drop`) which can modify the DataFrame in place. What you were using (boolean indexing) is also fine but that cannot modify a DataFrame in place.

Answer (score 0):

df.drop([rows you want to drop], axis = 0)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, @Greg, but it doesn't seem to work.
This is what I tried:

    `for df in [df1, df2]:
        df.drop(df["Year"] > 2013, axis=0)`

And I got the same results: No change in the number of rows in my original DataFrames.

Comment: Try df.drop(df[df["Year"] <= 2013], axis=0, inplace = True)

Comment: I get:

`ValueError: labels ['Year'] not contained in axis`